# Why my sound driver is not working?

Tags: drivers, 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, microphone

I was trying to fix my audio driver because neither it was detecting my headphone's mic nor the built-in mic was recording audio. I ran `dmesg |grep snd_` in my terminal to fix but upon restart my sound driver also got disabled. I am just totaly out now and can't able to fix it.

[image: This is the screen am getting] and it's same for **Input** also.

```
barefaced@barefaced-HP-Laptop-15-bw0xx:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) I/O Memory Management Unit
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Stoney [Radeon R2/R3/R4/R5 Graphics] (rev da)
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 15b3
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Host Bridge
00:02.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Root Port
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Root Port
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Root Port
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Host Bridge
00:08.0 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1578
00:09.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 157d
00:09.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Audio Controller
00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 20)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 4b)
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 49)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 4b)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15b0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15b1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15b2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15b3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15b4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15b5
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device d723
barefaced@barefaced-HP-Laptop-15-bw0xx:~$
```

These are my drivers and buses of my system

```
barefaced@barefaced-HP-Laptop-15-bw0xx:~$ lspci -knn | grep Audio -A3
00:01.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device [1002:15b3]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8330]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
--
00:09.2 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Audio Controller [1022:157a]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8330]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
barefaced@barefaced-HP-Laptop-15-bw0xx:~$
```

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Please help me out.

Comment: Let's see if the kernel module is loaded. Post the output of `lspci -knn | grep Audio -A3`.

Comment: And what "method" did you use?

Comment: @Pilot6 I had embeded the word with the link

Comment: The link doesn't give any "method". This is a post about completely other hardware and OS. There are some comments with different suggestions. So what exactly you did? Please [edit] your question and add information there.

Comment: @Pilot6 updated my question with the output of ```lspci -knn | grep Audio -A3``` and as per the link I had followed i ran ```dmesg |grep snd_``` and then rebooted my my system. From after that the sound driver is not working.

Comment: `dmesg | grep snd_` couldn't do anything because it shows only some logs.

Comment: know then I just ran that command only and had a safe restart after that all happened :(